# GuiDesigner.ExpandSelection doesn't work in IdeaVim plugin inside of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim

I find the IntelliJ IDEA's feature of expanding the selection (`GuiDesigner.ExpandSelection`) very useful, but unfortunately, I could not make it work while using IdeaVim plugin.
Even thought when execute this vim command `:actionlist GuiDeisgner.*Selection`, this result is show

```
--- Actions ---
GuiDesigner.ExpandSelection                        <C-W>
GuiDesigner.ShrinkSelection                        <C-S-W>
```

I have tried remapping it explicitly inside of my `.ideavimrc` file by adding lines like:

`:nmap <C-w> <Action>(GuiDesigner.ExpandSelection)`

`:nmap <C-w> <Action>(GuiDesigner-ExpandSelection)`

I haved also tried restarting IntelliJ after changing the `.ideavimrc` file, and it didn't work.

I have also tried using `:map` or `map` instead of `:nmap`. didn't work either

I also tried mapping keybindings other than `Ctrl` + `w`, but none of them worked.

When I disable IdeaVim plugin, the selection expansion works as expected.

`GuiDesigner.ShrinkSelection` works properly when pressing `C-S-w` ,
But unfortunately `GuiDesigner.ExpandSelection` doesn't.

I have also noticed that the `EditorSelectWord` command is mapped by default to the same keybinding as shown below:

```
--- Actions ---
EditorSelectWord                                   <C-W>
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition) as a snap package on Ubuntu 22.04

IdeaVim version 2.0.0

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2492/ctrl-w-doesnt-play-well-with-vim-visual-mode-actions looks related.

Comment: I checked it out, but didn't seem so.

Comment: Feel free to file a new bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=VIM.